# Inject class in to view component with Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I have a custom WebView that I add to my layout xml:

```
<my.company.ui.ExtendedWebView />
```

It extends the native WebView:

```
class ExtendedWebView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, 
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,  defStyle: Int = 0) 
    : WebView(context, attrs, defStyle) {
// ...
}
```

How can I use Hilt to inject a `@Singelton` class in to the class above? Property injection? How should I annotate the class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I have found is that the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation needs to be on the View, the Fragment (if in a Fragment) AND the Activity. Because Annotations.

So consider you have your DI set up as follows:

```
/* CONTENTS OF com.org.app.di/dependencyModule.kt */
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewComponent::class)
object DependencyModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideDependency(@ApplicationContext context: Context): DependencyType
            = DependencyInstance(context)
}
```

And my Application is properly set up:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class SuperAwesomeApplication : Application()
/* Remember to reference this is the manifest file, under the name attricbute! */
```

Now if I have a View with an injected dependency:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SuperAwesomeView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dependency: DependencyType
    ...
```

I will get the error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: class com.app.org.ui.view.SuperAwesomeView, Hilt view must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Fragment or Activity.
...
```

So I added the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation to the Fragment containing the View:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SuperAwesomeFragment : Fragment() {
...
```

And then we get hit with the next error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Fragments must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Activity. Found: class com.org.ui.SuperAwesomeActivity
```

And so I've learned the annotations need to bubble all the way up, from View to (if in a Fragment) Fragment, to Activity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SuperAwesomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
```

Comment: Yup, I came to the same conclusion. Accepting this

Comment: I'm kinda late for the party, but I'm doing same as you but my `@Inject` is not working. There's something else can I do?

Comment: @quintin Balsdon Also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76911591/4134215

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your `singleton class` currently looks like this:

```
class ExampleSingletonClass( //... some dependencies) {
     //.. some other stuff
}
```

To make it a Singleton change it to:

```
@Singleton
class ExampleSingletonClass @Inject constructor( //... some dependencies) {
     //.. some other stuff
}
```

Then, to inject it into your `ExtendedWebView` do this:

```
class ExtendedWebView @JvmOverloads @Inject constructor(
    context: Context, 
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,  
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    private val exampleSingleton: ExampleSingletonClass // your singleton, doesn't need to be private.
   ) : WebView(context, attrs, defStyle) {
// ...
}
```

You don't need any `@AndroidEntryPoint` here, but your `Fragment / Activity` needs `@AndroidEntryPoint`

Comment: Thanks. If I do that I get `Types may only contain one @Inject constructor`. Should I remove the default parameters?

Comment: @filur Either remove the default parameter or create a second constructor with the default parameter and let it point to the first constructor. Do `@Inject` on the second constructor as well. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240472/types-may-only-contain-one-inject-constructor)

Comment: Gotcha. Could you please post a sample with the 2 constructor approach?

Comment: @filur I'm sorry but I saw that this is unfortunately not possible (at least how I tried to). Kotlin can't distinguish between two constructors just because one has a default value and the other not. It says `Conflicting overloads`. My solution: Just remove the default parameters if you can and if not, you have to live with the warning `Types may only contain one @Inject constructor`

Comment: Thanks, I suppose removing them wont hurt in this case, since the framework hopefully sets them.

Comment: @Andrew Also have a look at my question