# Constructor Injection in Custom View using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, dagger-hilt

> I want to inject analytics or frontPageSection in CustomView. I have achieved parameter(analyticsService) construct using hilt in CustomViews like

```
@WithFragmentBindings
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MessagesView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null, defStyle: Int = 0, private val frontPageSection: FrontPageSection = FrontPageSection()) : LinearLayout(context, attributeSet, defStyle),
    IPresenceAware by frontPageSection,
    IFrontPageSection by frontPageSection, OnItemViewedListener {
    @Inject
    lateinit var analyticsService: AnalyticsService
}
```

But as you see **IPresenceAware** and **IFrontPageSection** is associated to `frontPageSection` . So I must have to implement constructor injection. Now I have two choices to inject `analyticsService` to **CustomView** and pass it to **FrontPageSection** Or Inject **FrontPageSection** from **DI**.
But I need to pass `analyticsService` like

```
FrontPageSection(analyticsService)
```

**FrontPageSection.kt**

```
class FrontPageSection(private val presenceAware: PresenceAware = PresenceAware(),
    private val analyticsService: AnalyticsService? = null) : IFrontPageSection, IPresenceAware by presenceAware {
}
```

**IFrontPageSection.kt**

```
interface IFrontPageSection {
    fun initSection(viewEventName: String, sortOrderName: SortOrderName, onSectionTrackedListener: OnSectionTrackedListener? = null)

    fun isActive(): Boolean

    fun setHasContent(hasContent: Boolean)

    fun getHasContent(): Boolean

    fun getSortOrderName(): SortOrderName

    fun getSortOrder(): SortOrder?

    fun setSortOrder(sortOrder: SortOrder?)

    fun trackSection()

    fun acceptsDefaultBackground(): Boolean { return true }

    fun debugInfo()
}
```

**PresenceAware.kt**

```
class PresenceAware : IPresenceAware {
    private var currentPresence: Presence = Presence.UNSET

    override fun changePresence(presence: Presence) {
        this.currentPresence = presence
    }
    override fun getCurrentPresence(): Presence {
        return currentPresence
    }
}
```

**IPresenceAware.kt**

```
interface IPresenceAware {
    fun changePresence(presence: Presence)

    fun getCurrentPresence(): Presence

    fun isPresent(): Boolean {
        return getCurrentPresence() == Presence.FULL_PRESENT
    }

    fun isHidden(): Boolean {
        return getCurrentPresence() == Presence.HIDDEN
    }

    fun decidingChild(): View? = null
}
```

**Dependency Injection using Hilt**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface UtilityModule {
    
    @Binds
    fun bindFrontPageSection(frontPageSection: FrontPageSection) : IFrontPageSection
    @Binds
    fun bindPresenceAware(presenceAware: PresenceAware) : IPresenceAware
}
```

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64185898/4134215). I want to achieve this but my class isn't singleton. But it is not working for me