# Injecting Context into a Broadcast Receiver using Hilt/Dagger?

Tags: kotlin, broadcastreceiver, dagger-2, dagger-hilt, glance-appwidget

I am using `context()` in my `GlanceAppWidget()` for tasks like retrieving glanceId and updating app widget state. I am having issue with how I inject the `context` object.

I would like to use the dagger/hilt framework to inject the context into my `GlanceAppWidget()` constructor. See `MyWidget()` below.

However by injecting the context into `MyWidget`, I then need to pass the context as constructor parameter in `MyWidgetReceiver()` for `val glanceAppWidget`. Broadcast receivers are not meant to have constructor arguments so this gives me an Instantiation Exception.

How can I inject context into my GlanceAppWidget? Any help will be much appreciated.

Note: I have also tried using default arguments in `MyWidget()` to avoid providing context in MyWidgetReceiver but this throws ["Type may only contain one injected constructor"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240752/15597975).

```
@Singleton
class MyWidget @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val context: Context
) : GlanceAppWidget()
```

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
@Singleton
class MyWidgetReceiver @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val context: Context /*<-java.lang.InstantiationException when trying to inject into BroadcastReceiver*/
) : GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {

    override val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget
        get() = MyWidget(context)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things:

1. `GlanceAppWidgetReceiver` is a `BroadcastReceiver` thus you can't have constructor parameters. Also it shouldn't be a singleton. BroadcastReceivers are short-term living classes.
2. You can retrieve the context inside a `@Composable` function by calling `LocalContext.current`. Also you can retrieve the glanceId by calling `LocalGlanceId.current`

Thus you don't need to inject the context in the first place.

```
class MyWidget: GlanceAppWidget() {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val glanceId = LocalGlanceId.current
        //...
    }

}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyWidgetReceiver: GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {

    override val glanceAppWidget = MyWidget()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcel that is really helpful. Would you be able to provide a code illustration of how `GlanceAppWidget` and `GlanceAppWidgetReceiver` would operate without the context params. I still feel like i need context as updating app widget state and retrieving glanceId would happen outside of a composable function.

Comment: I updated the answer with your code. To update the widget outside of these classes you should use GlanceAppWidgetManager to obtain the GlanceId. Or simply call MyWidget().updateAll(context)
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/glance/appwidget/GlanceAppWidgetManager

Answer (score 1):

`onReceive` method of the BroadcastReceiver has the context as its argument. You probably want to bind your widget-creating logic to this method

```
fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent)
```

**EDIT:**

I did not noticed that you are using Glance. Since that, I recommend to stop using context in constructor and instead update `glanceId` and widget state when you will actually have access to context via some kind of method.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    glanceAppWidget.update(context)
}
```

MyWidget:

```
fun update(context: Context) {
   // do some work
}
```

In case when you will need update, you will simply send matching intent which will be received by the receiver.

Comment: I need to override glanceAppWidget and provide it a context arg, so the context needs to be available outside of onReceive